# Packet Loss of two in Router>Router>L3SW configuration

Tags: routing, vlan, ping, packet-loss, packet-tracer

So, I am working on this network simulation it is pretty basic.

When I initiate the first ping from 172.25.56.0/24 network to 10.151.0.0/16 network there is a loss of 2 packets. I understand, this happens because in the first two pings the arp tables are created. But I wanted to know is there a way that I can decrease these two packet drops to one packet drop.

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5GAUpOlYEi9blVBejFaV1NTWEU/view?usp=sharing) is the .pkt file. I have created the file using Packet Tracer 6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sometimes it is one, sometimes it is more, pings which could be dropped. There is nothing abnormal about this.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Okay, does this mean in a sufficiently large network even though the route is functional I might see a 0% success rate in the first ping ?

Comment: You shouldn't see a 0% success rate unless there really is a problem, or you have something blocking ICMP echo and/or ICMP echo reply. You may see the first ping dropped, sometimes the first two, but rarely more than that. This can even happen on a point-to-point link between two directly connected PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since both are creating their arp-entrys.
You could decrease the drops with entering the arp-entrys yourself into the tables.
After these two initial packets there's no loss on that connection.
And since it's just pings the drop doesn't matter in a practical way.
But that would be a nice solution if there is one.

I would call this "ping golf".
Played faster with a traceroute(6).

EDIT: Maybe I'm wrong, see comments.

Comment: Thanks @Luca. one of my instructors told me that there shouldn't be a ping loss of more than one in a network. So, I was thinking it was possible some way.

Comment: Well, thinking of it.
The first router should send a request to the second one, asking it if it knows the IP Range.
Maybe it's a timeout over than a hop?

Comment: Yes, Luca My instructor admitted that, it was wrong and it is acceptable to lose ping in the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

check the mtu size end to end, then you may have congestion somewhere specially if the packet loss in your peak time.